# Проблема PHP (int)

Tags: php

В общем делаю "лайки" для сайта посредством php и ajax. 
Получаю данные из POST запроса таким образом:

> ```
> $userId = (int) $_POST['id_user'];
> $newsId = (int) $_POST['id_news'];
> $type = $_POST['type'];
> ```

Проблема в том, что если убрать (int) и оставить просто `$userId = $_POST['id_user'];`, то скрипт не сработает (лайк не поставится, в БД не будут занесены необходимые данные и т.д.). В чем может быть проблема? Пробовал сменить (int) на (string) всё равно не работает.

Comment: В БД у полей user_hash и project_id типы varchar

Comment: я не совсем понимаю, почему запрос реагирует на тип переменной (они все равно должны одинаково в строку превратиться и быть распознаны мускулем как числа), но в чем проблема оставить каст `(int)`?

Comment: вот и я не понимаю почему запрос реагирует на тип переменной.. а проблема в том, что в переменную $userId приходит хэш ip адреса, к примеру 95a3e710c47245908e6c53dd1907caeb, а после (int) в БД заносится не весь хэш а только число 95

Comment: переходите на PDO и не забивайте себе голову подобной ерундой

Comment: @xenon, постарайтесь впредь не делать того, что плохо понимаете. Я был уверен, что там идет работа с числами, понятное длео что после каста там все отрежется.

Comment: @xenon, а теперь попробуйте хоть одним глазком почитать документацию про функцию `int()` (вообще, это желательно делать до того, как браться за код). И поймёте, что ведёт себя она абсолютно корректно, а проблему вы сами себе создали неправильной архитектурой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В запрос попадают данные как числа, обрамляя их в кавычки, вы говорите MySQL что это будут строки. Вообще `user_hash, project_id` должны быть в БД `int`.

```
$userId = $_POST['id_user'];
$newsId = $_POST['id_news'];
$type = $_POST['type'];

// проверяем, голосовал ранее пользователь за эту новость или нет
$sql = mysql_query("
    SELECT count(*) FROM `project_like` WHERE `user_hash` = '$userId' AND `project_id` = '$newsId'") or die(mysql_error()); 
    ...
    ...
mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO `project_like` (`user_hash`, `project_id`) VALUES ('$userId', '$newsId')
") or die(mysql_error());
```